# reading content returned from httpclient.sendasync

Tags: string, get, return, asp.net-core-mvc, dotnet-httpclient

I have this code:

```
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

using (var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://someurl.com"))
{
    requestMessage.Headers.Add("sessionId", "ABC123");
    delayresponse = client.SendAsync(requestMessage).Result;
}
```

I have tried a couple of other variations of this with no success. My aim is to make a GET request to an MVC controller, and then read the `Content` that is returned by that controller using `HttpClient`. The returned `Content` is a `string`. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Do you get `200` indicates the request return response correctly?

Answer (score 1):

For access the `string` result, you could read from `Content` like:

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, @"http://localhost/IISWindows/home/test"))
        {
            var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
            var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
```

For another way, you could try `GetStringAsync`

```
            var result = client.GetStringAsync(@"http://localhost/IISWindows/home/test").Result;
```